# Are there any current multi-threaded sftp Windows clients?

Tags: windows, scp, sftp, winscp

I found bitkinex.com had one, but is rather old and doesn't support the latest encryption.

winSCP has it on it's plan, some time way into the future, but doesn't seem likely to happen.

Comment: WinSCP [allows background transfer operations to use multiple connections](https://winscp.net/tracker/show_bug.cgi?id=875) since WinSCP 5.10 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Are there any current multi-threaded sftp Windows clients?**

Below is a list of ones I was able to find claiming to support multi-threading which support SFTP.

> ### Multi-threading vs Segmented
>
> A common misconception is that multithreading = segmented downloading.
>   This is not the case. GoFTP is a client that claims to support
>   multi-threading, but in truth doesn’t offer segmented. Segmentation
>   allows an FTP client to split a single large file into multiple parts
>   and use multiple transfers to download those parts simultaneously (ie
>   - separate segmented parallel FTP connections). These parts are then recombined into a single file upon completion. During the active
>   download you’ll notice multiple (temporary) parts of the same file:
>
> **Client Setup**
>
> **Windows:** [CuteFTP Pro](https://www.globalscape.com/cuteftp), [SmartFTP Pro](https://www.smartftp.com/), [lftp via
>   Cygwin](https://nwgat.ninja/lftp-for-windows/)

[**SOURCE**](https://whatbox.ca/wiki/Multi-threaded_and_Segmented_FTP)

Comment: Didn't think about it that way, but yeah segmented is what I'm after. Thank you